# Tornado import error: 'no named module singledispatch'

Tags: python, tornado

After I installed tornado, upon testing an instance, it shows the error `no module named singledispatch`.

But when I import tornado it's ok.

Need help.

Comment: Show us some code, and also its expected behaviour. Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

Somehow you installed Tornado without its required dependencies. Install them with:

```
python -m pip install singledispatch backports_abc
```

[Here's the list of new dependencies in Tornado 4.3](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/releases/v4.3.0.html?highlight=singledispatch#installation).